# Magento 2 add new attribute using addAttribute()

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute

I am currently trying to programatically add a new attribute from the module I have created, but so far without success. I am using the below:

```
<?php

namespace COMPANY\MODULENAME\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if ($context->getVersion() && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'chat_lat',
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Chart latitude',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 1,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
                    'group' => 'Product Details',
                ]
            );

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'chat_lng',
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Chart longitude',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 1,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
                    'group' => 'Product Details',
                ]
            );

        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Obviously I have the correct company and module name specified in the namespace - this is just to protect the client. I have also run `magento setup:upgrade`, which seems to run fine.

Comment: Please use this tool might be help you thanks https://mage2gen.com/

Comment: @NagarajuKasa Where do I specify the Magento version with that tool? My understanding is that there are quite big differences between 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2. The code I generated from that tool doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that my issue was the version of the upgrade script set to 1.0.1, yet my module (`module.xml`) was set to 1.0.0. Changed the module to 1.0.1, ran `magento setup:upgrade`, and all is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

Please try as mentioned below.

```
 <?php

namespace Stackexchange\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);       

          $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'more_information',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'More Information',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => null,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'system' => 1,
                'group' => 'General',
                'option' => array('values' => array(""))
            ]
        );


    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work for me. Please could you advise the issue with the code in my original question?